# Get the size in KB of Marshal.dump output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, marshalling

I'm using `Marshal.dump` to serialize an array of objects, I need to get the size (in KB) of the returned value. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the output of `Marshal.dump` is a string, you can just ask for the length of that. The safest way to do this is to ask for `bytesize`:

```
dumped = Marshal.dump(array)
kb = dumped.bytesize / 1024
```

The `bytesize` method always returns the length of a string in bytes, whereas `length` returns the length of the string in characters. The two values can differ if you use a multi-byte encoding method like UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

What about `kbytes = Marshal.dump(ary_of_objs).size / 1000.0`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var = Base64.encode64(Marshal.dump(@result))
var.size
```

is life saver for me

Comment: I know nothing about RoR but this doesn't seem right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378815/base64-length-calculation