# a single character in Base64String holds how many bytes? 1, 2 or more

Tags: android, character-encoding, base64, heap-memory, android-memory

In my Android application the requirement is to fetch the images from the server and cache them into the heap memory.

On receiving the request, the server first encodes the `byte[]` into `Base64String` and returns that string. And, at the time of rendering it into `ImageView` the Android application decodes the `Base64String` back to the `byte[]`, creates a `Bitmap`, and puts it on `ImageView`.

As everything is in cache, there are chances the Application to go out of memory at some point, and crash critically.

To prevent the out of memory situation, I have defined a **safety quantum** (E.g. 5 MB) in my application. If at any point the available memory goes below to this **safety quantum**, user would then need to mark some of the images as the candidates to be deleted. Along with, the application would show the **estimated memory** going to be released once the selected items are cleared.

The `Bitmap` has been recycled once user moves away from the image, so the `Bitmap` effectively isn't holding any memory as long as we are away.

In a particular test, I download 55 images, and my heap grows from `16 MB` to `42 MB`. That means, 55 images occupy `26 MB`. After I clear all of them, the heap shrinks back to `16 MB`.

But, when I take a cumulative sum of lengths of all `Base64String` it comes to `11983840`. And if I consider one character as `1 byte` the `11983840 bytes` makes `11.4 MB`

The problem is, cumulative sum of the lengths of `Base64String` is the only measure available to me, that helps to let user know how much memory can be released by his selection.

I have also read the following question, which mentions, for each `3 Bytes` of original data the `Base64String` will have `4 Characters`.

[Base64 length calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378815/base64-length-calculation)

The question is,
a single character in `Base64String` holds how many bytes? 1, 2 or more

If `1 character` is `1 byte`, 
and in my test the heap grows and shrinks by **26 MB**. Then why the cumulative sum of the lengths of `Base64String` is only **11.4 MB**?

**Updated**

[image]

This means `1 Byte` per character.

[image]

The default CharacterSet here is UTF-8

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378815/base64-length-calculation?lq=1

Comment: I have already referred the link and hence have kept it as part of my question as well. The problem in the link and this are quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets start from the beginning...

Base64 is an encoding format based upon a set of 64 characters - each character is worth 6 bits of data (2^6 = 64). So when converting, each 8-bit byte of input needs (8 / 6) = 1.333333... characters.

But since computers only store whole bytes, it's easier to say that for every 3 bytes (3*8=24 bits) of input, 4 base-64 characters are produced (4*6=24 bits).

Now, you say your base-64 string total length is 11 million characters. In Java, strings are stored in 16-bit Unicode format: 1 character = 2 bytes.

So 11 million characters will use over 20 MB just in the raw character data. That, combined with objects, variables and other state needed to store the information means that 26 MB is a reasonable value for the amount of data you are using.

So a general rule you might want to use to estimate memory usage is (((input_data_in_bytes * 4/3) * 2) + a few MB)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its really a nice explanation. But, the question still remains open, because in my latest finding I seen the default character as UTF-8. Please check the "Updated" section in the question.

Comment: @Wayofhope I think you're confused. The `defaultCharset()` value represents the charset used when your Java program *interacts with your operating system* - it's to do with encoding data when reading and writing from streams and other I/O. It has nothing to do with how the characters are stored within the Java String type, which is always 16 bit unicode. As documented in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html  *A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format...*

Comment: Hi adelphus, thanks for the explanation. I might be wrong, but just want to dig into the bottom of it. For the String "Hello", why does "Hello".getBytes().length returns me 5?

Comment: @Wayofhope You're calling `getBytes()` which, according to the Java docs, *Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset,*. You've already demonstrated that your platform's charset is UTF-8, so `getBytes()` will convert from the Java String internal format (UTF-16) and return "Hello" as 5 UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: Now this solves my confusion. It takes a lot of patience and competence to explain in depth, that too with an online exchange medium. Kudos for that. Will seek more & more knowledge from you in future :)