# Random bytes to string type conversion

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, base64

Trying to get a random string of using urandom.

```
#! python3

from os import urandom
from base64 import b64encode
from sys import getsizeof

random_bytes = urandom(16)
salt = b64encode(random_bytes).decode('utf-8')

print("Random Bytes:", random_bytes)
print(type(random_bytes))
print(getsizeof(random_bytes))
print(len(random_bytes))

print("")
print("Salt:", salt)
print(type(salt))
print(getsizeof(salt))
print(len(salt))
```

Below is the instance of output which I'm unable to understand.

```
Random Bytes: b'.v\x9c\xa0\xda\xa4\x92@d\xfc>\xb1\xccZ)\xff'
<class 'bytes'>
33
16

Salt: LnacoNqkkkBk/D6xzFop/w==
<class 'str'>
49
24
```

Why the lenght of output in random bytes is 16-bytes whereas decoded string is 24-bytes?
What getsizeof is representing?

Answer (score 1):

Because `b64encode` also pads the value, as discussed [in this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378815/base64-length-calculation) question and as also specified in [the appropriate section of RFC 3548](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548.html#section-2.2).

The output value is `4 * math.ceil(n/3)` long, so, in case of `n == 16` equals `24`.

`getsizeof` represents the memory size for the `bytes` and `str` object respectively.