# Why does a byte array's size not equal a strings size?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, size, byte

I'm trying to understand how an array of bytes size is smaller than a strings. I know each character of a string is like 2 bytes or something.  But even that math is not adding up.  Can someone shed some light for me please?

The following:

```
byte[] myBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345");
string myString = Convert.ToBase64String(myBytes);
Debug.WriteLine("Size of byte array: " + myBytes.Length);
Debug.WriteLine("Size of string: " + myString.Length);
```

Returns:

> Size of byte array: 5
>
> Size of string: 8

Comment: Look at the resulting B64 string - it will be 8 chars

Comment: @Plutonix correct it ends up being `MTIzNDU=`.  But that is the problem, I expect the script to be `12345` not `MTIzNDU=`.  That's where my confusion is.

Comment: Why would it stay the same if you encode it differently?  Base64 != ASCII

Comment: Note that it will make the round trip - using the bytes from `MTIzNDU=` you can get the original back

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The sizes/lengths do match, but only if you use a 1:1 encoding.

First, you seem to be a bit confused as to what encoding is. Remember that bytes are just numbers (ranged 0-127) and are the *only* thing storable by a computer. Those numbers don't *mean* anything to humans other than numeric value. Because we wanted to be able to store the idea of **text**, we had to come up with a way to map these numbers to readable (and some not so readable) characters. These methods are called *encodings*.

You encoded your bytes with Base64 encoding, which has overhead (approximately 1 extra byte per 3 bytes of input according to [Base64 length calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378815/base64-length-calculation)). That overhead is causing your difference.

If you used `Encoding.ASCII` instead:

```
byte[] myBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345");
string myString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myBytes);
Console.WriteLine("Size of byte array: " + myBytes.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Size of string: " + myString.Length);
```

You get as expected:

> Size of byte array: 5
>
> Size of string: 5

The reason to use Base64 (even with overhead) is that it can encode *any* byte array into printable characters (which is required when trying to send them say, via a URL), whereas ASCII encoding will result in unprintable characters for quite a few values.

Also note that a character is only two bytes in a UTF-16 encoding, which is why your number isn't double like you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the encoding explanation as well!

Comment: fantastic explanation  !