# Encoding byte data and storing as TEXT vs storing in BYTEA in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some byte data(millions of rows), and currently, I am converting to base64 first, and storing it as TEXT. The data is indexed on a row that contains base64 data. I assume Postgres does the conversion to base64 itself.
Will it be faster if I store using BYTEA data type instead?
How will the indexed queries be affected on two data types?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Converting bytes to text using Base64 will consume 33% more space than bytes. Even this *would* be faster, you will use quite more space on disk. Loading and storing data should be slower as well. I see no advantage in doing that.

Postgres supports indices on `BYTEA` columns. Since the bytes are shorter than the text, byte columns with indexes should be faster than text columns with indices as well.

Comment: bytea is slower than text, http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/bytea_versus_text_in_postgresql/

Comment: @AuthorProxy: Unfortunately, the test is not very meaningful because it does not select according to the column. The test also includes implicit encoding and decoding operations that can produce completely different timings with other programming languages or adapters.

Comment: @ciemens, Incorrect info of how many times more space base64 encoding uses. It's 1.33%: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13378842/2821632

Comment: @AhmadFerdous: Thanks, you‘re right. I‘ve updated my post.

Comment: @nick-t why did you change 1.33% back to 33% in `@clemens` answer?

Comment: @uberrebu "1.33 more space" to me implies 2.33x total space. Could also phrase it "1.33 times the original space"

Comment: read @AhmadFerdous comment above and `@clemens` comment