# How to calculate Base64 encoded string length?

Tags: java, base64

I've read [following topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13378842/2674303) and found this formula there:

```
length = 4*(n/3)
```

I started to test it:

1 symbol:
`Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("1".getBytes())` =>`MQ==`(4 symbols)

2 symbols:
`Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("12".getBytes())` =>`MTI=` (4 symbols)

5 symbols:
`Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("12345".getBytes())` =>`MTIzNDU=`(8 symbols)

8 symbols:
`Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("12345678".getBytes())` =>`MTIzNDU2Nzg=`(12 symbols)

21symbols:
`Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("123456789012345678901".getBytes())` => `MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAx` (28 symbols)

Looks like this formula doesn't work.

Can you please explain mu results?

Comment: It looks like you should take to ceil of (n/3). e.g - Ceil(8/3) = 3. To for your forth example the calculation will be- 4 * Ceil(8/3) = 4 * 3 = 12

Comment: With ceil, it's a *bound* rather than an exact result. It's a guide to aid scaling calculations.

Comment: 22 symbols: **Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("1234567890123456789012".getBytes()) =>*MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMg==(32 symbols)

Comment: 22*3/4 =29.3333

Comment: @gstackoverflow `4*ceil(22/3) = 4*8 = 32`.

Comment: @Bohemian Do you happen to have an example when `4*ceil(n/3)` does not give an exact result?

Comment: @lexicore, yes it works. Thank you

Comment: @Kram Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

With 64 digits (2<sup>6</sup>) one digit can represent 6 bits.
Hence 4 digits can represent exactly 4*6 bits = 3 bytes.

*(Using `÷` for explicit integer division:)*

With n bytes, 4*(n÷3) digits are needed plus for the remainder n%3 (0 < 3 bytes) there is a need for 0 upto 4 digits:

```
0 bytes (0 bits)    0 digits
1 byte  (8 bits)    2 digits (12 bits)     + "=="
2 bytes (16 bits)   3 digits (18 bits)     + "="
```

Often there is a padding upto 4 digits/padding chars, using `=`.
This cannot be `0` as one then would add a byte 0x0.

Then the formula is `4 * Math.ceil(n / 3.0)`.

Without padding: `Math.ceil(n * 8 / 6.0)` = `Math.ceil(n * 4 / 3.0)` = `(n * 4 + (3 - 1)) ÷ 3`.

In java one should use int division only:

```
int base64Length(byte[] b) {
    int n = b.length;
    return (n * 4 + 2)/3;
}
```

Comment: I understood 4 * Math.ceil(n / 3.0). Bit it is not cleat where did take (12 bits) and (18 bits)

Comment: @gstackoverflow for 1 byte one needs 2 digits (8 <= 12 bit) and for 2 bytes one needs 3 digits (16 bit <= 18 bit).

Comment: 4*Math.ceil(16 / 3.0) == 20

Comment: `4*Math.ceil(16 / 3.0) = 4 * ceil(5.333) = 4 * 6 = 24` Ceil being round-up.

Comment: you are correct but how did you calculate this line: **2 bytes (16 bits)   3 digits (18 bits)     + "=" **?

Comment: To represent one byte (8 bits) with digits, one needs at 2 digits à 6 bits = 12 bits. One digit could only represent at most 6 bits payload. From those 12 bits, 4 bits are free: in effect one of 16 different digits would do. But in general the free bits are zeroed.

Answer (score -2):

Try length = 4*((n/3) + 1), where "/" is integer division.

Edit: Lexicore is correct, my formula fails when the remainder is zero.

```
int length = 4 * (n / 3);
if (n % 3 > 0) length++;
```

Comment: `4*((n/3) + 1)` gives `32` for `n=21` whereas the correct answer is `28`.