# Limit the file size in camera plugin ionic2 cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic2, camera

In my code i have tried to upload file from gallery. For that i have used camera plugin and tried to allow only less than 50MB files. Is there any way to restrict the file size while browse from gallery. Below is my code.

```
this.camera.getPicture({
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, // <== try THIS
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.VIDEO,      
}).then((imageData) => {
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: The imageData is a base64 string. You could figure out how many bytes it is and error if it is greater than 50 million. Here is something that gets the number of bytes for a base64 string (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378815/base64-length-calculation)

Comment: Thanks @MattKuhns.