# How to long is urn life

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

how long does I get urn in my code on derivativesApi

Autodesk.Forge.Model.DynamicJsonResponse translateResponse = derivativesApi.Translate(job, true);
                    string responseUrn = translateResponse.Dictionary["urn"].ToString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're asking the string length of the base64 urn.

It depends on the characters of the `objectId` (a.k.a object urn returned by [PUT /buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/)) you passed into the base64 string encoder with my experience, and it will be the same urn you pass to the [POST job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) of the Forge Model Derivative API. Normally, each Base64 digit represents exactly 6 bits of data from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and here is a formula to calculate the encoded string length [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378815/base64-length-calculation):

```
((4 * n / 3) + 3) & ~3
```

**note1.** `n` is the string length of your `objectId`.

For instance, the length of the `urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mybucket/example.txt` is 47. After base64 encoding, the result `dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bXlidWNrZXQvZXhhbXBsZS50eHQ=` length is `((4 * 47 / 3) + 3) & ~3 = 64`.

**note2.** The padding character `=` must be removed while triggering Forge translation jobs manually, Forge Model Derivative API doesn't allow it. Here is the formula:

```
len of the urn = 64 - n of the padding character `=`
```

Therefore, the final string length of the urn you obtain from the API response is `64 - 1 = 63`.

Ref. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

**note3.** Unless you call [DELETE :urn/manifest](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE/) to deleted the translated results (a.k.a.viewable bubbles), viewable bubbles will be stored in Forge server permanently. You can also use viewable bubbles' urn to access them, despite the model file stored in your managed OSS bucket is deleted by the [bucket policy](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/) you have set up.

Comment: I ask the available time of the urn code generated in autodesk viewer(derivativesApi)

Comment: Hi, I think the note3 converted the lifetime of the URN.

Comment: I ask this question for the api that autodesk offers

Comment: My bad, if you're asking what is the timing you can obtain the URN, here is my answer. Once you uploaded your model to Forge server via Data Management API https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/, it will returns `objectId`, a.k.a the `urn`. Before submitting a translation job, you have to convert this `urn` into `based64 urn`, . After doing this, you got the `urn` you request immediately. It's the same as the one you asking `translateResponse.Dictionary["urn"].ToString();`.

Comment: The link is `PUT /buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName` mentioned above, https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/ . However, I edited it, it should be a good link.

Comment: I want to know how long I can use this urn code. The  urn code I produced 1 time lived 4 days. How many days will live?

Comment: As I mentioned, the urn is just a link to the viewable bubbles. It will live until you call DELETE :urn/manifest to remove it from Forge server. Could you tell more about this `The urn code I produced 1 time lived 4 days`??

Comment: can I use the code unless I delete it? the main answer to this problem