# Strange URL encoding characters at the end of CSRF Tokens Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to learn how to use Laravel Sanctum authentication. When I send `GET https://localhost/sanctum/csrf-cookie` I get the following CSRF cookies:

```
XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Inhvb0FDVXdHZDU5QzBqQTNKaWNxTUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSXNudjNiNE9xbmtNVWdsQ0l2SDRyYUNPQXIrTGJLb2ZMVDc2NWttenZGY0NkcDRvQzFVQlZOMDRlNFdTOHJaNiIsIm1hYyI6ImY0Y2M2YzZiZWIxYWVmZTRmMWI5NWRhNTBhN2JmM2VjNGExYjU0MGYwYWVmYTE4ODQxM2I0YTFlMWVjZTVhMDkifQ%3D%3D;
```

You can notice the strange %3D%3D at the end of the token. These characters also added for my laravel_session cookie.
When I then send back a request with this exact token in the header X-XSRF-TOKEN, I'm getting token mismatch error. When I remove the characters - all works. I wonder where's these characters came from and how can I remove them.

**UPD:** since those were encoded URL characters, when I decoded them and put '==' instead at the end of X-XSRF-TOKEN, that seems to be working. Still, it's strange why it worked before when I just removed the characters from the query manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this stands for the `=` symbol which is part of your base64'ed CSRF token. I'd guess it only works when you remove it because the `=` symbol is the special [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29) character. In a very high level they just pad the string out to the proper length.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, `=` becomes `%3D` when it is url encoded.

Usually when you encounter a string with lot of numbers and characters in random order and it ends with `==` there is a very high probability that it is encoded in base64.

`=` is added (at the end of the string) as padding to match a specific number of characters in a string. You can read more about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13378815/base64-length-calculation).

To answer your question, I will try decoding the given token with and without `==` at the end, I'll use [this online decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/), so you can try it at your end aswell.

With `==`:

```
{"iv":"xooACUwGd59C0jA3JicqMA==","value":"Isnv3b4OqnkMUglCIvH4raCOAr+LbKofLT765kmzvFcCdp4oC1UBVN04e4WS8rZ6","mac":"f4cc6c6beb1aefe4f1b95da50a7bf3ec4a1b540f0aefa188413b4a1e1ece5a09"}
```

Without `==`:

```
{"iv":"xooACUwGd59C0jA3JicqMA==","value":"Isnv3b4OqnkMUglCIvH4raCOAr+LbKofLT765kmzvFcCdp4oC1UBVN04e4WS8rZ6","mac":"f4cc6c6beb1aefe4f1b95da50a7bf3ec4a1b540f0aefa188413b4a1e1ece5a09"}
```

They are **same**.

It works because they (`=`) are just padding and they DO NOT contain any information.

I am no laravel expert but, I am guessing the reason it doesn't work with `%3D` is because it is not decoding the url.