# openssl AES CTR send output in C

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes

I need to send an encrypted data through a socket in C. So I make my payload like:
`message_type|flags|message_1|message_2`

I want to encrypt the `message_x` with AES.
For security concerns, I need to keep the `message_x` length for the ciphertext. That's why I am using the OpenSSL [AES-CTR](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_aes_128_ctr.html) mode.

But there's the problem. The output is completely awful, like �3Y������ȳ�_�[��. And there are characters like `[`, `_`, etc. Every character could appear in the output. So the receiver won't be able to unserialize the payload because, perhaps, the delimiter (`|` in the example) has been generated by AES...

I saw `base64` conversion could do the trick. But the conversion changes the length of the ciphertext (like explained in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13378842/12069515)).

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: So, base64 doesn't enough for you?

Comment: As mentionned, base64 changes the ciphertext length, but I need to keep it the same